# Type mismatch, GameObject Arrays, Unity 2022.3.10f1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have this Scriptable Object class which I want to store diferent arrays of gameObjects, these gameObjects are prefabs with a mesh and an empty inside of it. when trying to assign, draging gives me the forbidden sign in my mouse pointer, and when I try to assign it lets me assign those prefabs but once I do it shows only Type mismath. the code for the scriptable Object is:

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "NewPathData", menuName = "PathData")]
public class PathData : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] pathObjects;

    public GameObject[] GetPath()
    {
        return pathObjects;
    }
}```
````

Comment: You do understand that gameobjects exist only in a scene, and are remade every scene load, game run etc, therefore storing them outside would be pointless?

Comment: Where did you drag from to where?

Comment: Okey, first off I had no idea that gameObjects work like BugFinder suggested and second I dragged them from the scene to the array.

Comment: For some added context, I am tryong to currently create a copy of Mario party, this is so the player can at given locations choose diferent paths, but I dont know if the logic I am using to move trough the tiles is the best available. I could give more info on how it works if anyone is interested.

Comment: ScriptableObject are **assets** ... you can't really have scene references in assets in most cases as it makes little sense. They are unloaded as soon as the scene unloads => your references will be pointing nowhere. (There is an exception for runtime set references - they will still appear as "Type mismatch" though) .. it should work though if those are actually **prefab** assets - and not scene instances

Comment: Objects in the scene are not prefabs. Prefabs are in the project window.

Comment: `ExposedReference<T>` is exactly for that: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExposedReference_1.html.